Repeated event long format data to single multiple variable
I have a repeated observations in long format
ID      Approach Date
-42365 Sternotomy 18-11-2022
-42365 Thoracotomy 22-03-2024
-11234 Thoracotomy 12-03-2018
-11234 Sternotomy 17-05-2023

I have to convert it to this using dplyr or any other packge:
ID     Approach_1    Date_1   Approach_2 Date_2
-42365 Sternotomy  18-11-2022 Thoracotomy 22-03-2024
-11234 Thoracotomy 12-03-2018 Sternotomy 17-05-2023



Do you want to reshape data from long to wide in R?

Yes, it is somthing like reshaping from long repeted to wide, but using dplyr system.

It works, thanks a lot. Only thing it complains that if ID is  throws an error, I have converted it to character.

I cannot reproduce the error, ID is read as integer and it shouldn't make any difference but I have coerced it to "numeric", aka C's double, and still no error.

The trick is to create a unique identifier since the ID alone isn't one, then play with pivot_*.
df1 <- read.table(text = "ID      Approach Date
-42365 Sternotomy 18-11-2022
-42365 Thoracotomy 22-03-2024
-11234 Thoracotomy 12-03-2018
-11234 Sternotomy 17-05-2023", header = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(cnt = seq_along(Approach), .by = ID) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(ID, cnt)) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = ID,
    names_from = c(name, cnt),
    values_from = value
  )
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>       ID Approach_1  Date_1     Approach_2  Date_2    
#>    <int> <chr>       <chr>      <chr>       <chr>     
#> 1 -42365 Sternotomy  18-11-2022 Thoracotomy 22-03-2024
#> 2 -11234 Thoracotomy 12-03-2018 Sternotomy  17-05-2023

Created on 2024-10-14 with reprex v2.1.1
